# Dynamic command line arguments are not getting passed to the script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, command-line-arguments

Here is my pipeline script where I'm calling one shell script and passing the arguments. In this $np and $cp contains special character i.e. # ex: abcdefgh#abd#we23:

```
def name = 'xyz'
def np = ''
def cp = ''
def pnumber = 'if.com'
def mnumber ='12'
def unumber= 'abc'
pipeline{
 stages{

stage('stage1'){
steps{
  script{
      cp = sh(script: "cat file.txt", returnStdout: true)
      np = sh(script: "cat file2.txt", returnStdout: true)
     }
}

stage('stage2'){
steps{
  script{
      sh "./myscript.sh $name $mnumber $pnumber $unumber $np $cp"
     }
}
}
}
```

Where as my script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$1
pnumber=$2
mnumber=$3
unumber=$4
np=$5
cp=$6
sqlplus $unumber/$np/$cp/$unumber/$mnumber/$pnumber<<EOF
  select date/$name;
  exit;
EOF
```

Output of the pipeline script I'm getting is without the last argument. For example:

```
./myscript.sh abc xyz 123 User abcdefgh#abd#we23
```

it is not taking the last argument.

Request your help in letting me know what is wrong with my script. I'm happy to provide you any other detail if required.
Thanks

Comment: check your scripts with shellcheck. Is `$6` a groovy variable or a shell variable? I think `"$6"` should result in groovy compilation error, no? Is this real code?

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk - if argument is not having that special character i.e. # then it is working as expected. I would like to know how to bypass these characters dynamically.

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk - I'm not getting any compilation error and it is a shell variable. it's just that $6 is not being taken up during the script compilation.

Comment: In the `sh "./myscript.sh $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6"` Is `$6` a groovy variable or a shell variable? Is this real code, or is it rather `./myscript.sh ${some_groovy_variable}`? Are you fine with using `sh './myscript.sh $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6'`?

Comment: @gauravsharma, create [mcve]. Current posted excerpt of pipeline is not very useful: it's unclear how you are passing parameters into your script.

Comment: There's a mismatched double quote on the sqlplus line.

Comment: Hi @glennjackman - updated that..

Comment: @markalex - let me update the question for more clarity.

Comment: hi @KamilCuk - only $5 and $6 are shell variables. Rest all are defined as groovy variable.

Comment: Sadly I don't know the Groovy based Jenkins well, so some questions: How does i.e. the Groovy variable $1 its value? If i.e. $5 is really a shell variable and not a Groovy variable, it would be the fifth positional parameter; where do you pass a value to this variable? How does Groovy know that $1 to $4 are Groovy vars, and $5 and $6 is a shell variable?

Comment: Then` $1` should be an exception - there is no variable named `1` in groovy.

Comment: @KamilCuk - I have updated the question correctly

Comment: @user1934428 - I have updated the question for better understanding now

Comment: `np` and `cp` are set to the context of `file.txt` and `file2.txt`.  Since you don't show us the content of these files, we don't know what's in these variables. Without knowing what exactly is stored in the variables, we can't explain how the parameters in the script are filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple is to add single quotes to shell side and come back to the problem when you have `'` in the password or other variables:

```
sh "./myscript.sh $name $mnumber $pnumber $unumber '$np' '$cp'"
```

The most reliable is to pass everything with env variables and then shell can quote it properly.

```
environment { 
    name = name
    number = number
    pnumber = pnumber
    unumber = unumber
    cp = readFile "file.txt"
    np = readFile "file2.txt"
}
script {
    sh './myscript.sh "$name" "$mnumber" "$pnumber" "$unumber" "$np" "$cp"'
}
```

Or you can serialize ex. to json and read it in a shellscript (or in python because it can import json).

You might want to research the groovy string interpolation rules and shell quoting rules and shell expansions. Groovy interpolates the string, which is then evaluated by shell quoting. It is a nightmare. https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4

Then your script should be fixed too - it is missing quoting. Post it on shellcheck and implement suggestions.

Note that your files could contain a trailing newline. Shell command substitution `$(...)` removes trailing newlines. You might want to remove them in groovy or in bash.

Comment: first option I already tried and it is not able to resolve the issue. I will check on the second option you provided.

Comment: Hi @kamilCuk - First option actually worked for me ... yesterday I missed one quote in the script. I'm accepting this as an answer. thanks !!!